# TypeScript test if value instance of Record

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to test if a value is an instance of a `Record` type in TypeScript?   I want a case that properly distinguishes when the variable could potentially also be an array.

```
function(a: Record<string,string>|string[]) {
  if( a instanceof Record ) {
     do_stuff( a.key )
  }
}
```

I know this is problematic in JavaScript because both of my types are objects, thus `typeof(a) == "object"` in both cases. I'm hoping there's perhaps a special TypeScript way to accomplish this.

*I understand the `Record` type doesn't really exist at runtime, but the example should clarify what I'm trying to do.  It's also important that the test properly informs TypeScript of the narrowed type, so that `a.key` doesn't produce an error.*

Comment: Why not test whether it's an array instead? TypeScript understands `Array.isArray`, for example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKZQBYzAcwAoBDALkQCUMI4AnAEwB5kpa98AaFV9gPkQA+3NgQDaAXQCUiAN4AoRIhjBEhAIQBBWrWIBPAHQxkWnbpKTp8xYuL6A1hl0LEAXzlugA

Comment: There is no `Record` value/class. THis is only a type

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess my example wasn't complete enough, there might be other types in the union, so eliminating the array wouldn't be enough to say it's a record type.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type), a `Record<K, V>` is an object whose keys are `K` and values are `V`. A "true" `Record<string, string>` doesn't exist because of the prototype chain, which causes objects to inherit e.g. a `.toString()` method. But taking into consideration the complete set of inherited properties would be cumbersome ([related discussion on the TS GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30875)), so it's clearest to think of the `Record` type working with [an object's own properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties):

```js
// Allowed:
const foo: Record<string, string> = { bar: "bar" }

// Even though functions aren't a subtype of string:
type inheritedToString = typeof foo.toString
//   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//   inheritedToString = () => string
```

This means you'll most likely get far enough by combining one or many of the ways of [iterating over properties in an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties#traversing_object_properties) with TypeScript's [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```js
function isStringRecord(obj: unknown): obj is Record<string, string> {
  if (typeof obj !== "object")
    return false

  if (Array.isArray(obj))
    return false

  if (Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj).length > 0)
    return false
  
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
    .every(prop => typeof obj[prop] === "string")
}
```

Now you'll have:

```
const foo = { bar: "bar" } as unknown

if (isStringRecord(foo)) {
  foo // foo: Record<string, string>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be to use type guards to narrow the type of a based on its runtime value. You can do this by defining a type guard function that checks the value of a and returns true if it is of the expected type, and false otherwise. For example, you could define a type guard like this:

```
function isRecord(a: Record<string, string> | string[]): a is Record<string, string> {
  // Check if a is an object and has a property called "key"
  return typeof a === 'object' && 'key' in a;
}
```

Then, you can use this type guard in the if statement to narrow the type of a based on its runtime value:

```
function doStuff(a: Record<string, string> | string[]) {
  if (isRecord(a)) {
    // At this point, TypeScript knows that a is of type Record<string, string>,
    // so you can safely access its properties without getting a type error.
    doSomething(a.key);
  } else {
    // a is not a Record, so it must be an array of strings
    doSomethingElse(a);
  }
}
```

This approach allows you to properly distinguish between the two types and access their properties without getting a type error.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to create a more specific solution, you could do:

```
function isRecordNotArray(
    thing: Record<PropertyKey, unknown> | unknown[]
): thing is Record<PropertyKey, unknown> {
    return !Array.isArray(thing)
}
```

Note that `PropertyKey` is just a built-in shorthand for `string | number | symbol`. Then, you could do:

```
function(a: Record<string,string>|string[]) {
    if(isRecordNotArray(a)) {
        do_stuff( a.key )
    }
}
```

Even though the type guard function `isRecordNotArray` only narrows the type down to `Record<PropertyKey, unknown>`, the TypeScript compiler knows in this context that `a` is *either* `Record<string,string>` specifically *or* `string[]` specifically, and so it knows that the type is the narrower `Record<string,string>`, not just the broader `Record<PropertyKey, unknown>`.